# How to ingest CDC events produced by Oracle CDC Source Connector into Snowflake

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, apache-kafka-connect

Our current pipeline is following a structure similar to the one [outlined here](https://medium.com/vimeo-engineering-blog/debezium-event-flattening-with-sql-in-snowflake-b0e8397cfac2) except we are pulling events from Oracle and pushing them to snowflake. The flow goes something like this:

- [Confluent Oracle CDC Source Connector](https://www.confluent.io/hub/confluentinc/kafka-connect-oracle-cdc) mining the Oracle transaction log
- Pushing these change events to a Kafka topic
- [Snowflake Sink Connector](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/kafka-connector-overview.html) reading off the Kafka topic and pulling raw messages into Snowflake table.

In the end I have a table of `record_metadata`, and `record_content` fields that contain the raw kafka messages.

I'm having to build a set of procedures that handle the merge/upsert logic operating on a stream on top of the raw table. The tables I'm trying to replicate in snowflake are very wide and there are around 100 of them, so writing the SQL `merge` statements by hand is unfeasible.

Is there a better way to ingest the Kafka topic containing all of the CDC events generated from the Oracle connector straight into Snowflake, handling auto-creating nonexistent tables, auto-updating/deleting/etc as events come across the stream?

Comment: SO is not the right place for asking about opinions or suggestions. If you have a code problem in any of the components, edit your question and describe your code and what error you are getting. But if you look for advices, anyone can have a different opinion, and it is not the purpose of SO. Read this https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255468/opinion-based-questions

Comment: You can use stream-processors (KSQL/Kafka Streams, Spark, Flink, etc) **before** the sink connector to massage the data into a format that you want, and write that into new topic(s)